# How to create derived class with "derived input class"?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++14, derived-class

I have a base class

```
    class BaseClass
    {
    public:
        BaseClass(const <std::shared_ptr<inputClassForBase>>& input)
    }
```

I would like to create derived class so that the input they take must be derived from inputClassForBase, e.g.:

```
    class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
    {
    public:
        DerivedClass(const <std::shared_ptr<inputClassForDerived>>& input)
        :
        BaseClass(input)
    }

    class inputClassForDerived: public inputClassForBase
    {}
```

How should that be done? I know that in C# there are generics but in C++ it's much harder to put constraints to the class member/argument. I tried going down the path of making BaseClass a template class, but then it seems like I can either use it as a template **OR** a base class, but not both. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use both templates and inheritance, as in `class DerivedClass : public BaseClass<inputClassForDerived> { ... };`. But then you can't use `BaseClass` as a polymorphic base class, as you can't create simple pointers or references of `BaseClass`.

Comment: _"the input they take must be derived from inputClassForBase"_ I don't get what you mean. What is wrong with the code in the question (apart from the extra <>)?

Comment: I presume that the derived class constructor calls the base class constructor with the input pointer. For that to be possible, `inputClassForDerived` would have to be derived from `inputClassForBase` so the constraint is already there.

Comment: @Indiana that's right, the derived class constructor calls the base class constructor with the input pointer. But before making the base class a template class, that didn't work

Comment: Aren't you running into the issues that some programmer dude mentioned in the initial comment?

Comment: @IndianaKernick I have only taken some programmer dude's advice in solving my original problem; I haven't tried the part of using `BaseClass` as a polymorphic base class, if that's what you mean

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what your initial problem was! ...and how you solved it!

Comment: I edited the original post slightly to make it more clear. The code as it is won't compile because I was passing inputClassForDerived into the BaseClass constructor

Comment: Am I missing something here? Your code compiles fine and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't. `std::shared_ptr<inputClassForDerived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<inputClassForBase>`.

Comment: @IndianaKernick not quite fine... Lots of missing semicolon and braces, class definitions should be reordered too.
PFChang, could you edit the question to provide the exact example that fails to compile?

Comment: @IgorG Ok, I shouldn't have said "compiles fine" but it does compile after you fix those issues. I mean, why wouldn't it?!

Comment: I would have a C2664 error: cannot convert argument from `const <std::shared_ptr<inputClassForDerived>>` to `const <std::shared_ptr<inputClassForBase>>`

Answer (score 3):

The code snippets posted in the question suffer from numerous syntax errors and confusing order of class definitions. Once fixed, the code compiles just fine and doesn't require any generic templates:

```
#include <memory>

class inputClassForBase
{
};

class inputClassForDerived : public inputClassForBase
{
};

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(const std::shared_ptr<inputClassForBase>& input);
};


class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass(const std::shared_ptr<inputClassForDerived>& input)
     : BaseClass(input)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Actually I have simplified my code a bit, in my real use case I have `const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<inputClassForBase>>& ` and `const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<inputClassForDerived>>& `. Must be the vector that is making the difference.

Comment: @PFChang That makes a huge difference! vectors aren't implicitly convertible!